# How to copy a Ruckus ZF7363 configuration?

Tags: wireless

I have two Ruckus Outdoor APs, Model ZF7363. One has already been configured, and the other is not configured. I am using ZoneDirector.

How do I copy the configuration from the one already setup to the empty one?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the AP's are connected with Flex-Master[Ruckus Management Software], then you can push the AP configuration templates from one standalone to another.

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly the same way you have configured your first ZF7363.
Since you are using ZD to manage ZF, you need to follow these steps.

1. Configure your ZD with your required parameter(WLAN GROUP, IP Address and so on).
2. Connect your ZD into the network.
3. (optional)Enable DHCP server in ZD(Either if there is no other DHCP server available, or if you configure each ZF with static ip address)
4. Connect ZF into the network.
5. Approve your ZF in ZD dashboard(it might not be required depending on ZD configuration).
6. Assign WLAN group to ZF.

You just need to repeat step 4-6 for each ZF.